# Laravel session resets on GET request in another tab

Tags: php, laravel, session

I'm having trouble with Laravel sessions.

I can't seem to get Laravel session data to work.

> 1. Open 2 tabs with different pages on my project
> 2. Clear session data
> 3. Reload tab 1 and all session data (errors) are fine
> 4. Reload tab 2 (Simple GET request)
> 5. Return to tab 1 and no errors are getting displayed anymore no matter how many times I try.

I use Laravel Framework version 5.2.39.

Routes are in "web" middleware group by default.

Session directory has 777 rights.

I have checked almost every Google result regarding this issue.

**Update:**

I have found out that if I change 'encrypt' => true, to 'encrypt' => false,
in config/session.php it works as intended..

Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: Is it all session data or just errors? And which kind of errors? If it's validation errors or errors that you're sending using `->with('x', 'y')`, those are stored in the session as flash data, meaning they intentionally only have a lifespan of one request.

Comment: @BenChamberlin Seems like new session is being generated on tab 2.. I'm trying to return errors using withErrors($validator), but the problem is that any request in tab 2 will break tab 1 error messages.. After I reload tab 2, tab 1 can't receive any error messages no matter what I try (Only deleting cookies helps)

Comment: change your SESSION_DRIVER to file in config/session.php i think it will do the trick

Comment: @BindeshPandya It is already set that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

As told by @BindeshPandya SESSION_DRIVER had to be set to file..

I thought I did that long ago, but my .env had "cookie" value.. Silly me